# Kotlin check if elements in list with erased type are instances of a Java class

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

I have a class that stores a `resultClass` and I want to do some type checking and make sure users get a type safe list when calling the `getTypeSafeResults` function.

```
class MyClass<T>(
    private val resultClass: Class<T>
){
    fun getTypeSafeResults() : List<T> {
        val results: List<Any?> = remoteFetchResults()
        return results.filterIsInstance(resultClass)
    }
}
```

This API must be Java friendly, hence why resultClass is a Java class.

But, when `resultClass=Integer::class.java` / `resultClass=Long::class.java`, and the results contain the Kotlin version of these e.g. kotlin.Int / kotlin.Long, they do not match the `filterIsInstance(resultClass)`.

Is there is a way to manually check if the resultClass is the Java version of the Kotlin type? I've tried along the lines of this snippet below but had no luck:

(When `it` is a kotlin Long, `it.javaClass.kotlin="class kotlin.Long"` but `resultClass="long"`)

```
fun getTypeSafeResults(results: List<Any?>) : List<T> {
    return results.map {
        uncheckedCast(
            if (resultClass.isAssignableFrom(it.javaClass)) { // doesn't match kotlin long to java Long
                it 
            } else if (it.javaClass.kotlin == resultClass) { // doesn't match kotlin long to java Long
                it
            } else {
                throw Exception("Attempted to cast result of type ${it.javaClass} to $resultClass")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it work with `results.filter { it.javaClass == resultClass } as List<T>`?

Comment: No that didn't work, resultClass is `"long"` and it.javaClass is `"class java.lang.Long"`. Neither did `resultClass == it::class.javaObjectType` or `resultClass == it::class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some experiments to understand better what's going on.

All of these correctly find 42:

```kotlin
val list = listOf(42, 32L, "bob")
println(list.filter { it::class == Int::class })
println(list.filter { it::class == java.lang.Integer::class.java.kotlin })
println(list.filter { it::class == Int::class.java.kotlin })
println(list.filter { it.javaClass == Int::class.javaObjectType })
println(list.filter { it.javaClass == java.lang.Integer::class.java })
```

Only this doesn't:

```kotlin
println(list.filter { it.javaClass == Int::class.java })
```

What you can do is therefore ensure you're using the `javaObjectType` on the class the users give you:

```
class MyClass<T : Any>(
    resultClass: Class<T>
){
    private val effectiveClass = resultClass.kotlin.javaObjectType

    fun getTypeSafeResults() : List<T> {
        val results: List<Any?> = remoteFetchResults()
        return results.filterIsInstance(effectiveClass)
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor: `::class.java.kotlin` is the same as `::class`

Comment: @Lino in theory yes, but since I'm using `equals()` I wanted to check that going back and forth didn't mess up with equality. That is important because users of that lib would pass a `Class<T>`, so the OP's class wouldn't have access directly to the `::class` version. Anyway I have to admit that if there is any difference, it would most likely only be visible when using different classloaders

Comment: When I try `resultClass.kotlin.javaObjectType` I get `None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val <T : Any> Class<TypeVariable(T)>.kotlin: KClass<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.jvm`

Comment: @bonapart3 ah, you need to add a type bound on `T` in `MyClass`'s declaration, like this `T : Any`. Because `.kotlin` only works on non-nullable types I guess (otherwise they are not classes per se). I edited my answer.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I need to allow nulls. So a workaround I was able to `return results.map { if(it == null) { uncheckedCast(it) } else if ((resultClass as Class<*>).kotlin.javaObjectType == it.javaClass) { return uncheckedCast(it) } else { throw...}` - see anything obviously wrong about this cast?

Comment: @bonapart3 I'm not sure about *how* you can allow a `T?` here. How do you expect users to provide a Java `Class<T>` where `T` is nullable? I don't believe this is possible. So in effect `T` itself is never nullable and you should put the `: Any` bound. If you want to allow null *items* in the output list, it's a different story and you can simply change your return type to `List<T?>`. Your users will have to deal with nullable elements all the time though, in that case. In any case, the code in your comment is lying about the return type `List<T>` and the unsafe cast is wrong in the null case.